# Paperclip Cropping rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I referred this episode of railscasts
http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images

But whenever I press on the crop button
I get an error

convert.exe: invalid argument for option `-crop': 'YYYxYYY+YYY+YYY'-auto-orient
@ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1124.

Y being the values depending on the selected area.

Please suggest me to rectify this bug.

This is my controller code:

```
 def crop_photo
    @artist_profile=ArtistProfile.find(params[:id])
    @artist_profile.update_attributes(params[:artist_profile])
    if @artist_profile.save
      format.js
    end
```

My cropping view file :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.Jcrop" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.Jcrop" %>
<div style="max-width: 720px;">
<%= nested_form_for @artist_profile, :url => cropped_photo_path ,:html => { :method => :post } ,:remote => true do |f| %>
<%= image_tag @artist_profile.photo.url(:large), :id => "cropbox" %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "artist_profile_id", @artist_profile.id %>
<h4>Preview:</h4>
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden">
<%= image_tag @artist_profile.photo.url(:thumb), :id => "preview_image" %>
</div>
<% for attribute in [:crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h] %>
<%= f.hidden_field attribute, :id => attribute %>
<% end %>
<p><%= f.submit "Crop" %></p>
<% end %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {
  $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
    onChange: update_crop,
    onSelect: update_crop,
    setSelect: [0, 0, 500, 500],
    aspectRatio: 1
  });
});

function update_crop(coords) {
  var rx = 100.00/coords.w;
  var ry = 100.00/coords.h;
  $('#preview_image').css({
    width: Math.round(rx * <%= @artist_profile.photo_geometry(:large).width %>) + 'px',
    height: Math.round(ry * <%= @artist_profile.photo_geometry(:large).height %>) + 'px',
    marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
    marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
  });
  var ratio = <%= @artist_profile.photo_geometry(:original).width %> / <%= @artist_profile.photo_geometry(:large).width %>;
  $("#crop_x").val(Math.round(coords.x * ratio));
  $("#crop_y").val(Math.round(coords.y * ratio));
  $("#crop_w").val(Math.round(coords.w * ratio));
  $("#crop_h").val(Math.round(coords.h * ratio));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post your code for passing the params to the crop command?

Comment: @RichPeck:Updated with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your system is either not sending or processing the required crop co-ordinates:

1. Javascript is not updating the hidden fields
2. JCrop is not capturing / processing the right data
3. Rails is not reading the params properly

---

**JS**

You may want to write your JS code like this:

```
var jCrop = function() {
  $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
    onChange: update_crop,
    onSelect: update_crop,
    setSelect: [0, 0, 500, 500],
    aspectRatio: 1
  });
};

$(document).ready(jCrop);
$(document).on("page:load", jCrop);
```

Your JCrop could be prevented from loading due to not loading correctly

---

**JCrop**

The other issue you may have is JCrop not capturing the right data

You need to make sure your hidden fields are actually getting populated with the data. Your `update_crop` code looks okay - so I would look at `view_source` > `hidden fields`

---

**Rails**

The likely problem here is probably Rails' processing of the params

You're passing your form_for var as `@artist_profile`

I would do this in your controller (considering you're using Rails 4):

```
 def crop_photo
    @artist_profile = ArtistProfile.find(params[:id])
    @artist_profile.update_attributes(crop_params)
    if @artist_profile.save
      format.js
    end
 end

 private

 def crop_params
     params.require(:artist_profile).permit(:crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_h, :crop_w)
 end
```

Comment: Ah that's quite a problem! Why don't you upgrade?

Comment: The decision is not upon me.Can you please suggest me any pros of upgrading?

Comment: As with all software ( & things ), newer versions are more flexible, powerful, robust, tested, etc. Rails is up to v4 now - you really should look to upgrade as it's a big step above v2. But if you can't it's okay